# JSON Parse API response ends in unexpected token " " at position

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

Whenever I fetch the getContractABI Endpoint of etherscan and try to parse the response.data to JSON I get the error of unexpected tokens.

```
exports.getContractABI = async (contractaddress) => {
    try {
        let response = await axios.get(
            `https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${contractaddress}&apikey=${API_KEY}`
        );

        let result = JSON.parse(response.data);
        cconsole.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(contractaddress, error);
    }
};
```

When I hit the endpoint in the browser the responded data looks like this

{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tokenTransferProxy","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"target","type":"address"},{"name":"calldata","type":"bytes"},{"name":"extradata","type":"bytes"}],"name":"staticCall","outputs":

Can anyone elaborate why its not able to parse to JSON here? doesnt etherscan check for valid responses on their heavily priced API?

Comment: The json output seems missing the last part. Since it is a closed source api you have to ask etherscan customer support.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to solve this? I am getting the same problem as well but it sometimes work???

Comment: It appeared that my error was occurring due to contract not being verified and thus I was trying to parse a non-existent ABI.